# How to import a file from a different subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble importing a dynamically named script from a different directory. I take a string as input, which corresponds to a python module with the needed class, "model". My directory structure is shown below.

For example, string "v1" would mean import "models/v1.py" as mod and getting the model class from that module.

I've tried multiple iterations of the importlib package, as well as appending my sys path to find the needed module, but to no avail.

> - app
>
>   > - models
>   >
>   >   > - v1.py
>   >   > - v2.py
>   > - src
>   >
>   >   > - utils.py

Comment: Where are you importing the models? From src/utils.py or from some file under app/?

Comment: @GinoMempin I am trying to import 'app/models/v1.py' into 'app/src/utils.py'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) function:

```
models = __import__('models', fromlist=['v1'])
```

Comment: I'm still getting a "No module named 'models'" error. I tried using '../models' but then the function only tries to import '.', which fails.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use

```
sys.path.append('..')
```

before

```
model = __import__('models.v1', fromlist=["v1"])
```